# React/Material UI Drawer With Nested List Items Closes on Click

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, material-ui

I am using Material-UI for my React project and having issues with getting the drawer to function properly when I add in nested list items. Everything was working great until I added those in. I believe the root cause is that by clicking on the dropdown menu and changing the state of the list item to be open I'm causing the application to re-render. Not sure how to solve this.

**Problem:** Nested list items close the drawer automatically when you click the top level. The user then has to open the drawer again to see the list items in the drop down.

**Desired Functionality:** The user clicks the menu item to open the drawer. The user can click on "Leadership Triad" and see the menu items within while the drawer stays open. When the user clicks off, the drawer closes.

**Code Sandbox**
https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-nested-menu-forked-qqdiv

**My Code**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import AppBar from "@material-ui/core/AppBar";
import Toolbar from "@material-ui/core/Toolbar";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
import IconButton from "@material-ui/core/IconButton";
import MenuIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Menu";
import Drawer from "@material-ui/core/Drawer";
import List from "@material-ui/core/List";
import Divider from "@material-ui/core/Divider";
import ListItem from "@material-ui/core/ListItem";
import ListItemIcon from "@material-ui/core/ListItemIcon";
import ListItemText from "@material-ui/core/ListItemText";
import InboxIcon from "@material-ui/icons/MoveToInbox";
import HomeIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Home";
import AccountCircle from "@material-ui/icons/AccountCircle";
import ExitToAppIcon from "@material-ui/icons/ExitToApp";
import ExpandLess from "@material-ui/icons/ExpandLess";
import ExpandMore from "@material-ui/icons/ExpandMore";
import PeopleIcon from "@material-ui/icons/People";
import BusinessIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Business";
import Menu from "@material-ui/core/Menu";
import MenuItem from "@material-ui/core/MenuItem";
import { Link as RouterLink } from "react-router-dom";
import Collapse from "@material-ui/core/Collapse";

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
    root: { flexGrow: 1 },
    menuButton: { marginRight: theme.spacing(2) },
    title: { flexGrow: 1 },
    list: { width: 250 },
    nested: { paddingLeft: theme.spacing(4) },
}));

const Header = () => {
    const [drawerOpen, setDrawerOpen] = useState(false);
    const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = useState(null);

    const [leadershipTriadMenuOpen, setLeadershipTriadMenuOpen] = useState(false);

    const handleLeadershipTriadClick = () => {
        setLeadershipTriadMenuOpen(!leadershipTriadMenuOpen);
    };

    const handleClick = event => {
        setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
    };

    const handleClose = () => {
        setAnchorEl(null);
    };

    const toggleDrawer = () => {
        setDrawerOpen(!drawerOpen);
    };
    const classes = useStyles();
    return (
        <div className={classes.root}>
            <AppBar position="static">
                <Toolbar>
                    <IconButton
                        edge="start"
                        className={classes.menuButton}
                        color="inherit"
                        aria-label="menu"
                        onClick={() => toggleDrawer()}
                    >
                        <MenuIcon />
                        <Drawer
                            anchor="left"
                            open={drawerOpen}
                            onClose={() => toggleDrawer()}
                        >
                            <div className={classes.list}>
                                <List>
                                    <ListItem button component={RouterLink} to="/">
                                        <ListItemIcon>
                                            <HomeIcon color="primary" />
                                        </ListItemIcon>
                                        <ListItemText primary="Home" />
                                    </ListItem>
                                    <ListItem
                                        button
                                        onClick={() => handleLeadershipTriadClick()}
                                    >
                                        <ListItemIcon>
                                            <HomeIcon color="primary" />
                                        </ListItemIcon>
                                        <ListItemText primary="Leadership Triad" />
                                        {leadershipTriadMenuOpen ? (
                                            <ExpandLess />
                                        ) : (
                                            <ExpandMore />
                                        )}
                                    </ListItem>
                                    <Collapse
                                        in={leadershipTriadMenuOpen}
                                        timeout="auto"
                                        unmountOnExit
                                    >
                                        <List component="div" disablePadding>
                                            <ListItem button className={classes.nested}>
                                                <ListItemIcon>
                                                    <HomeIcon />
                                                </ListItemIcon>
                                            </ListItem>
                                        </List>
                                    </Collapse>
                                    <ListItem button>
                                        <ListItemIcon>
                                            <InboxIcon color="primary" />
                                        </ListItemIcon>
                                        <ListItemText primary="Testing" />
                                    </ListItem>
                                    <ListItem button>
                                        <ListItemIcon>
                                            <InboxIcon color="primary" />
                                        </ListItemIcon>
                                        <ListItemText primary="Testing" />
                                    </ListItem>
                                </List>
                                <Divider />
                                <List>
                                    <ListItem
                                        button
                                        component={RouterLink}
                                        to="/admin/companies"
                                    >
                                        <ListItemIcon>
                                            <BusinessIcon color="primary" />
                                        </ListItemIcon>
                                        <ListItemText primary="Companies" />
                                    </ListItem>
                                    <ListItem
                                        button
                                        component={RouterLink}
                                        to="/admin/users"
                                    >
                                        <ListItemIcon>
                                            <PeopleIcon color="primary" />
                                        </ListItemIcon>
                                        <ListItemText primary="Users" />
                                    </ListItem>
                                </List>
                                <Divider />
                                <List>
                                    <ListItem button component={RouterLink} to="/profile">
                                        <ListItemIcon>
                                            <AccountCircle color="primary" />
                                        </ListItemIcon>
                                        <ListItemText primary="Profile" />
                                    </ListItem>
                                    <ListItem button component={RouterLink} to="/logout">
                                        <ListItemIcon>
                                            <ExitToAppIcon color="primary" />
                                        </ListItemIcon>
                                        <ListItemText primary="Logout" />
                                    </ListItem>
                                </List>
                            </div>
                        </Drawer>
                    </IconButton>
                    <Typography variant="h6" className={classes.title}>
                        Leadership Program
                    </Typography>
                    <IconButton color="inherit" onClick={handleClick}>
                        <AccountCircle />
                    </IconButton>
                    <Menu
                        id="admin-menu"
                        anchorEl={anchorEl}
                        keepMounted
                        open={Boolean(anchorEl)}
                        onClose={handleClose}
                    >
                        <MenuItem
                            component={RouterLink}
                            to="/profile"
                            onClick={handleClose}
                        >
                            Profile
                        </MenuItem>
                        <MenuItem
                            onClick={handleClose}
                            component={RouterLink}
                            to="/logout"
                        >
                            Logout
                        </MenuItem>
                    </Menu>
                </Toolbar>
            </AppBar>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Header;
```

Comment: The thing is the `<IconButton>` (parent) of the drawer has the onClick  listener so try and give the onClick listener to individual  `ListItem` and dont give it to that `ListItemIcon`

Comment: Did you try doing this ^^^^ (the above solution)

Comment: @GayatriDipali thank you so much, sir! That worked really well. I just moved the onClick to the MenuIcon itself rather than the button since the button was the parent.

Comment: @GayatriDipali I did get an error that said I need to have the onClick on a parent element. What I did was keep the onClick listener where I had it, but moved the Drawer code outside of the IconButton so it's no longer the parent. Problem solved.

Comment: like now does it work as expected

Comment: ok fine you moved that  `ListItemIcon` outside the icon button?

Comment: I moved out the entire Drawer so it was no longer the child of the button, but a sibling.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried surrounding the IconButton with a ListItemSecondaryAction?

```
<ListItemSecondaryAction>
  <IconButton onClick={handleOnClick}>
    {openState ? <ExpandLess /> : <ExpandMore />}
  </IconButton>
</ListItemSecondaryAction>
```

I was trying to do something similar, where a list item had two clickable areas with two different actions: click the ListItem (to go to a page) or click the IconButton (to expand the ListItem) to display nested ListItems. Without this ListItemSecondaryAction, when I would click on a list item, it would both route and expand the ListItem, which was not desirable.

Adding the SecondaryAction separated click actions of the ListItem and the IconButton. The documentation isn't great, so it took me a while to understand the purpose, but it's [here](https://material-ui.com/api/list-item-secondary-action/#listitemsecondaryaction-api).

Comment: Thanks but my problem is already solved. See comments underneath my original post.